# test for multicollinearity in glmnet models

Tags: r, glmnet

Is there a way to test for multicollinearity before running `glmnet`?
The `vif` function from `car` is giving me an error:

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(apply(mtcars, 2, scale))
y <- mtcars2$mpg
x <- as.matrix(mtcars2[,2:11])
fit <- glmnet(x,y, lambda = .5)

vif(fit)

Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('elnet', 'glmnet')"
```